# Give a unique ID number based on certain condition in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I would like to give a unique ID number in a data frame (df) based on certain conditions in the df. My df looks like this:

```
dfin <-
STUDY   DRUG  FED  DOSE  TIME  CONC
 4       0     1    50    2     10
 4       0     1    60    4     25
 5       1     1    10    5     20
 12      0     0    50    2     10
```

And so on. I want to add a unique ID number for each unique combination of `STUDY, DRUG, FED, DOSE`. The output for the above should be like this:

```
dfout <- 
STUDY   DRUG  FED  DOSE  TIME  CONC  ID
 4       0     1    50    2     10    1
 4       0     1    60    4     25    2
 5       1     1    10    5     20    3
 5       1     0    10    5     25    4  
 12      0     0    50    2     10    5
```

I would need help on how to do this in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the point of the `.GRP` variable in `data.table`, see `?data.table`:

> `.GRP` is an `integer`, length 1, containing a simple group counter. 1 for the 1st group, 2 for the 2nd, etc.

Usage:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfin)[ , ID := .GRP, by = .(STUDY, DRUG, FED, DOSE)]
```

Also it's not clear you had `data.table` in mind when you tagged the question; if this is the case, see the [Getting Started](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) tutorials.

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful. `data.table` was just a thought. I know that there are lots of things that can be done with it in data frame but I am still R beginners and didn't have clear vision on how I can possibly do it.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, we can use `group_indices_`

```
library(dplyr)
dfin %>%
    mutate(ID= group_indices_(., 
        .dots= c("STUDY", "DRUG", "FED", "DOSE")))
#   STUDY DRUG FED DOSE TIME CONC ID
#1     4    0   1   50    2   10  1
#2     4    0   1   60    4   25  2
#3     5    1   1   10    5   20  3
#4    12    0   0   50    2   10  4
```